# Snake died, unsure of the cause

Tags: eating, snakes, death

I keep two baby carts in a twenty gallon task together, they are both female and have always gotten along just fine. I found them in their hide cuddling frequently,etc. I feed them both a pinkie every week at the same time, and they have overhead heat sources. I come home from work today to find the smaller one at the edge of the cage dead. She was crinkled up, her body so fiddling back and forth the whole way down. Her body did not uncurl when I lifted her up. Is indicative of any certain cause of death in snakes? I'd like to know what happened to her to protect the other one.

Comment: Can you include their age and how long you have had them?

Comment: Possibly related: http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2557/my-corn-snake-died-just-after-feeding-what-are-the-possible-causes